# Shiny - Click for next plot

Tags: r, shiny

```
for (i in 1:4){
  v <- rnorm(50)
  plot(v, main=paste("Iteration ", i))
}
```

I have code that iterates through and produces a plot each time, like the above. How would I allow a user to click to see the next plot in a Shiny application?

Comment: How your minimal reproducible shiny application looks like?

Comment: Could you give me some direction as to what I should look into? Plot just plots the last iteration

Comment: I don't like to give answers like "google it". But here try to type "plot shiny" and voilà: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/conditionalpanel-demo.html

Comment: Your plots are reactive or "predefined" ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `slickR` package to make a nice slideshow.

```
library(shiny)
library(slickR)
library(svglite)

plots <- lapply(1:5, function(i){
  xmlSVG({plot(rnorm(50), main=paste0("Iteration ", i))}, standalone = TRUE)
})
#make the plot self contained SVG to pass into slickR 
plotsAsSVG <- sapply(plots, function(sv){
  paste0("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,",as.character(sv))
})


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      ####
    ),

    mainPanel(
      slickROutput("slickr", width="500px")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$slickr <- renderSlickR({
    imgs <- plotsAsSVG
    slickR(imgs)
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]